# find rows with similar certain items in two tables

Tags: python

I have two tables with thousand rows, one has 6 columns, the other has 4. Both tables are sorted with the first column. They looks like:

```
296.526 10 0.1213 -0.907 0.005 -1.337
296.690 10 0.0000 +0.026 0.005 -0.404
296.936 11 0.1102 -1.885 0.005 -2.315 
297.010 10 0.1101 -0.717 0.020 -1.147
297.012 11 0.0873 —1.436 0.020 -1.866  
297.313 10 0.0873 -0.471 0.005 -0.901
...
```

and

```
 296.936 0.110 -2.252 0.037 
 297.012 0.087 -1.964 0.041 
 297.613 2.279 -0.968 0.041 
 298.144 0.052 -1.342 0.037 
 298.645 0.110 -3.088 0.045 
 299.442 0.052 -0.564 0.045 
 302.049 0.087 -0.846 0.045 
 ...
```

I want to find rows that the difference of their first columns are within `0.001`, and difference between the 3rd column of table 1 and the 2nd column of table 2 are within `0.001` too, then generate a new table by adding the 6th and 5th column of table 1. For example, I would like to get two rows of the new table from the table sections above:

```
296.936 0.110 -2.252 0.037 -2.315 0.005
297.012 0.087 -1.964 0.041 -1.866 0.020
```

I just start to learn python. How can I do this in python efficiently?

Comment: Sounds like a good homework problem. Do you have any coding attempt you can [include into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54547732/edit)? Should be easily accomplished with or without the `pandas` package

Comment: Yes, I search Pandas, It will be very easy to extract the "same rows" of tables. In the project, I would like to roughly match contents of two elements of rows (they don't need to be exactly the same, the are considered be matched if difference is within 0.001).  Tables could be tens of thousands rows, so loops may be slow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for:

```
table1 =[[296.936, 11, 0.1102, -1.885, 0.005, -2.315 ],[297.010, 10, 0.1101, -0.717, 0.020, -1.147],[297.012, 11, 0.0873, -1.436, 0.020, -1.866]] 
table2 =[[296.936, 0.110, -2.252, 0.037 ], [ 297.012, 0.087, -1.964, 0.041 ]] 
table3 = []
for i in range(len(table2)):
     for j in range(len(table1)):
          if float('{:.3f}'.format(abs(table2[i][0]-table1[j][0])))<=0.001 and float('{:.3f}'.format(abs(table2[i][1]-table1[j][2])))<=0.001:
               newtable = table2[i]
               newtable.append(table1[j][4])
               newtable.append(table1[j][5])
               table3.append(newtable)
print(table3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I know this (loops) will work for the purpose. But I am wondering whether it will be slow when there are tens of thousands rows in each table, and the memory may have issue to hold tables if they are really big. Of course, I can sort tables and cut them to pieces to speed up. Considering that this is a rather common problem, I am wondering there are any python packages for the purpose. Thanks again,